# How to completely remove ldap and remove the directory tree

Tags: ldap, openldap

so I followed this guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html

to install and configure ldap but then I discoverd both phpLDAPadmin and Luma and have decided to rebuild my tree from scratch using one of those tools. However Im not sure how to completely remove LDAP now. I can remove it using apt-get, but if I attempt to reinstall it and login using phpLDAPadmin it seems that it's still looking for older authentication and gives me a credential error

Comment: Might also need to remove /var/lib/ldap

Answer (score 4):

A simple `sudo dpkg-reconfigure slapd` should perform the task.

Comment: I mucked up my ldap configuration and this worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
apt-get remove --purge package
```

apt-get remove [--purge]  Removes  and any packages that depend on it. --purge specifies that packages should be purged

> **The difference between remove and purge is that while remove only deletes data and executables, purge also deletes all configuration files in addition.**

Comment: if you manually add file to ldap configuration directory, you should issue an addition command: `rm -rf /etc/ldap`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to remove the LDAP content, you can delete /var/lib/ldap/*.
Please remember to keep the DB_CONFIG (if existing) file in this directory since it is important for performance tuning of the DB backend.

Answer (score 0):

If you get into the error of

> **slapd is broken or not fully installed**

then you might try

```
$ mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/slapd.* /tmp/
$ dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq slapd
$ dpkg --purge slapd
```

[As suggested here.](https://adimian.com/blog/2014/10/how-to-fix-a-broken-ubuntu-package-installation-here-slapd/)